# How can I align this longtable?

Tags: align, longtable

I have enumerate

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\quad 1)]
\item $y =  (x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+7 x+10}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2+11 x-15}{2  \sqrt{x^2+7 x+10}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+5}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2+5 x-7}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+5}}$. \hfill  Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2-25 x+68}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2-17 x+26}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-43 x+93}{2 \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2-13 x+11}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-35 x+54}{2 \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (2 x-9)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-27 x+23}{2 \sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2-5 x-7}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (4 x-19)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-11 x-15}{2 \sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-2 x-3}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2+3 x-9}{\sqrt{x^2-2 x-3}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-3.$ \item $y = (x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-5 x+4}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-3 x-22}{2 \sqrt{x^2-5 x+4}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-4}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2+7 x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-4.$ \item $y = (x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+2 x-3}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2+11 x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+2 x-3}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-5.$ \item $y = (x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-x-2}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2+13 x-12}{2 \sqrt{x^2-x-2}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-4.$ \item $y = (x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(x^2-5 x-14\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+x-2}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2+21 x+5}{2 \sqrt{x^2+x-2}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-5.$ \item $y = (x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+9}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(x^2-3 x-18\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+9}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-3.$ \item $y = (x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+5}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2+19 x+35}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+5}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-7.$ \item $y = (x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x-20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(x^2-x-30\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x-20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-5.$ \item $y = (x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x^2-11 x-30}{\sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (2 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-41 x+100}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (2 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+4 x+3}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (4 x+9)}{\sqrt{x^2+4 x+3}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (2 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-33 x+63}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (2 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(2 x^2-25 x+68\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (2 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2+17 x+13}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (2 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-25 x+34}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (2 x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2+25 x+34}{\sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (2 x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-17 x+13}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (2 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-34 x+52}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (2 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-43 x+93}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (2 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-4 x+3}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (4 x-9)}{\sqrt{x^2-4 x+3}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (2 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-26 x+22}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (2 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-35 x+54}{\sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (2 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x (2 x-9)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (2 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-27 x+23}{\sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (2 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-1}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2+7 x-2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (2 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-35 x+31}{\sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (2 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(2 x^2-5 x-7\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (2 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (4 x-19)}{\sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (2 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+27}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (4 x-27)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+27}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (2 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x^2-11 x-15}{\sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (3 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2+31 x+25}{\sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (3 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+5}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x (3 x+11)}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+5}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (3 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2-91 x+165}{2 \sqrt{x^2-9 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (3 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+3 x+2}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (12 x+19)}{2 \sqrt{x^2+3 x+2}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (3 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(3 x^2-29 x+60\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (3 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-14 x+48}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-67 x+172}{\sqrt{x^2-14 x+48}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (3 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(2 x^2-25 x+68\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (3 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-7 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2-67 x+86}{2 \sqrt{x^2-7 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (3 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+5 x+6}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2+43 x+31}{2 \sqrt{x^2+5 x+6}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (3 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-46 x+68}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (3 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-55 x+111}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (3 x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-5 x+6}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2-43 x+31}{2 \sqrt{x^2-5 x+6}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (3 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+7 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2+67 x+86}{2 \sqrt{x^2+7 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (3 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-34 x+28}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (3 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-43 x+62}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (3 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-51 x+78}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (3 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (3 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-3 x+2}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (12 x-19)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-3 x+2}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (3 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2+91 x+165}{2 \sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-3.$ \item $y = (3 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x (3 x-11)}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (3 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-31 x+25}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (3 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 x^2-39 x+33}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (3 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2-35 x+54\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (3 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (6 x-19)}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (3 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 x (2 x-9)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (3 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2-27 x+23\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (3 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x (3 x-22)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (3 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(3 x^2-31 x+50\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (4 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-89 x+195}{\sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (4 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-113 x+365}{\sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=5.$ \item $y = (4 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(2 x^2-25 x+68\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (4 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2+34 x+26}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (4 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-50 x+68}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (4 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+27}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-73 x+114}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+27}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (4 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+63}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-97 x+260}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+63}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (4 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2+50 x+68}{\sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (4 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-34 x+26}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (4 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+16}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-57 x+49}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+16}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (4 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-14 x+48}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-81 x+171}{\sqrt{x^2-14 x+48}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (4 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(2 x^2-17 x+26\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (4 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (4 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-4 x+3}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x (4 x-9)}{\sqrt{x^2-4 x+3}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (4 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+7}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (8 x-41)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+7}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (4 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-65 x+98}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (4 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 x^2-52 x+44}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (4 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(4 x^2-35 x+54\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (5 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(2 x^2-25 x+68\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (5 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+7 x+10}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2+99 x+79}{2 \sqrt{x^2+7 x+10}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (5 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+30}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-171 x+333}{2 \sqrt{x^2-11 x+30}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (5 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2+131 x+182}{2 \sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (5 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-139 x+198}{2 \sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (5 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-131 x+182}{2 \sqrt{x^2-9 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (5 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-99 x+79}{2 \sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (5 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(5 x^2-43 x+38\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (5 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{10 x^2-131 x+364}{\sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (5 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(2 x^2-17 x+26\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (5 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (5 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{10 x^2-99 x+158}{\sqrt{x^2-14 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (5 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(5 x^2-57 x+126\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+60}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (5 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-7 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-91 x+71}{2 \sqrt{x^2-7 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (5 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-5 x+4}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (20 x-59)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-5 x+4}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (5 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+9}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 x (5 x-33)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+9}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (5 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+63}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{10 x^2-111 x+243}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+63}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (5 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(2 x^2-13 x+11\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (5 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-35 x+54\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (6 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-7 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2-67 x+86}{\sqrt{x^2-7 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (6 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2+17 x+13\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (6 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2-25 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (6 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+5 x+6}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2+43 x+31}{\sqrt{x^2+5 x+6}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (6 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(3 x^2-23 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (6 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(6 x^2-55 x+111\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (6 x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-5 x+6}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2-43 x+31}{\sqrt{x^2-5 x+6}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (6 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2+25 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (6 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2-17 x+13\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (6 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+7 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2+67 x+86}{\sqrt{x^2+7 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (6 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(3 x^2-17 x+14\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (6 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(6 x^2-43 x+62\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (6 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 \left(2 x^2-17 x+26\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (6 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (6 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-3 x+2}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{x (12 x-19)}{\sqrt{x^2-3 x+2}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (6 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-4 x+3}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 x (4 x-9)}{\sqrt{x^2-4 x+3}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (6 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{12 x^2+91 x+165}{\sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-3.$ \item $y = (6 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 x (3 x-11)}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+5}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=0.$ \item $y = (6 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(6 x^2-31 x+25\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (7 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+56}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{28 x^2-323 x+844}{2 \sqrt{x^2-15 x+56}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (7 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+24}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{28 x^2-235 x+358}{2 \sqrt{x^2-11 x+24}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (7 x-1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{28 x^2-275 x+573}{2 \sqrt{x^2-13 x+40}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (7 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+42}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{28 x^2-267 x+549}{2 \sqrt{x^2-13 x+42}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (7 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+14}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{28 x^2-179 x+151}{2 \sqrt{x^2-9 x+14}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (7 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{28 x^2-219 x+326}{2 \sqrt{x^2-11 x+28}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (7 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{7 \left(2 x^2-17 x+26\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (7 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{7 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (7 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+30}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{28 x^2-211 x+310}{2 \sqrt{x^2-11 x+30}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (8 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(4 x^2+17 x+13\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (8 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(4 x^2-25 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (8 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+27}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(8 x^2-73 x+114\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+27}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (8 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-16 x+63}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(8 x^2-97 x+260\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-16 x+63}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (8 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(4 x^2+25 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (8 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(4 x^2-17 x+13\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (8 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+16}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(8 x^2-57 x+49\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+16}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (8 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-14 x+48}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{2 \left(8 x^2-81 x+171\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-14 x+48}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (8 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{8 \left(2 x^2-17 x+26\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (8 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (9 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-19 x+90}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{36 x^2-523 x+1715}{2 \sqrt{x^2-19 x+90}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=5.$ \item $y = (9 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+5 x+6}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(12 x^2+43 x+31\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2+5 x+6}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (9 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 \left(3 x^2-23 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+21}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (9 x-3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(6 x^2-55 x+111\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+35}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (9 x-2)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+30}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{36 x^2-355 x+566}{2 \sqrt{x^2-13 x+30}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (9 x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+50}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{36 x^2-403 x+885}{2 \sqrt{x^2-15 x+50}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (9 x+3)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-5 x+6}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(12 x^2-43 x+31\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-5 x+6}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (9 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-17 x+72}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{36 x^2-451 x+1228}{2 \sqrt{x^2-17 x+72}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (9 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+7 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(12 x^2+67 x+86\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2+7 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (9 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{6 \left(3 x^2-17 x+14\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+12}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (9 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{3 \left(6 x^2-43 x+62\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-10 x+24}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (9 x+7)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-11 x+18}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{36 x^2-283 x+247}{2 \sqrt{x^2-11 x+18}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (9 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{9 \left(2 x^2-17 x+26\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (9 x+9)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{9 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$ \item $y = (9 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-13 x+36}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{36 x^2-331 x+518}{2 \sqrt{x^2-13 x+36}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (10 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2+17 x+13\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-1.$ \item $y = (10 x-5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-25 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (10 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2+131 x+182}{\sqrt{x^2+9 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (10 x-4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-139 x+198}{\sqrt{x^2-9 x+18}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (10 x+4)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-9 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-131 x+182}{\sqrt{x^2-9 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (10 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2+25 x+34\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+8 x+15}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=-2.$ \item $y = (10 x+5)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-17 x+13\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-6 x+8}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (10 x+6)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-99 x+79}{\sqrt{x^2-7 x+10}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (10 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{4 \left(5 x^2-43 x+38\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+20}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=1.$ \item $y = (10 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-262 x+728}{\sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=4.$ \item $y = (10 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{10 \left(2 x^2-17 x+26\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-12 x+32}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=2.$ \item $y = (10 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$, \quad $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. \hfill Answer. $x=3.$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to align derivative. I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}p{3cm}}
\toprule
Oder& The function    & Derivative of the function    & Solution of Derivative \\
\midrule
1&$y = (10 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$ & $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. & $x=3.$ \\
2&$y = (10 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$ & $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. & $x=3.$ \\
3& $y = (10 x+10)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}$ & $y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}}$. & $x=3.$ \\
4& $y = (10 x+8)\cdot \sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}$. & $y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-262 x+728}{\sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}}$& $x=4.$\\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How can I align this enumerate?

Comment: what is the question exactly? `{p{0.5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}p{3cm}}` is wider than the page so you need narrower columns. (it's easier to specify the width in `pt` rather than `cm` as then when tex reports how wide the table is you can easily adjust. You have to make the table 87pt (2cm or so) less wide  as TeX warns:`Overfull \hbox (87.11218pt too wide) in alignment at lines 6--16`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make the table fit inside the textblock. Some suggestions/observations:

- There seems to be no need for fixed-width columns. Use `c` instead.
- Move repeated pieces of information -- `y=`, `y'=`, and `x=` -- out of the body of the text and into the header.
- Omit all punctuation marks and `\cdot` directives. Doing so will help declutter the appearance of the table.
- Insert a bit more space between the rows, say, via `\addlinespace` instructions.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,longtable,booktabs,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic-mathmode version of "c"
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lCCC@{}}
\toprule
Order& \text{Function $y$} & \text{Derivative $y'$} & \text{Solution $x$} \\
\midrule
1 & (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54} & \dfrac{5 (4 x^2-43 x+93)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} & 3 \\ 
\addlinespace
2 & (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54} & \dfrac{5 (4 x^2-43 x+93)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} & 3 \\ 
\addlinespace
3 & (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54} & \dfrac{5 (4 x^2-43 x+93)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} & 3 \\ 
\addlinespace
4 & (10 x+8) \sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}  & \dfrac{20 x^2-262 x+728}{\sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}}  & 4 \\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a version of the `longtable` which (a) automatically inserts the row number in the first column and (b) provides more structure via `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and  `\endlastfoot` instructions. (Of course, the `\endfoot` and `\endhead` instructions don't come into play in the example code shown below, as the entire table fits on a single page.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,longtable,booktabs,array,etoolbox}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}} % automatic math mode version of "c"
\newcounter{rownum}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\stepcounter{rownum}\therownum}l}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\setcounter{rownum}{0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} N CCC @{}}
%% Header information, first page
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Order}& \text{Function $y(x)$} & \text{Derivative $y'(x)$} & \text{Value of $x$ for} \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{} & & & \text{which $y'=0$} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

%% Header information, all pages but first
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\footnotesize\em(continued from previous page)}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Order}& \text{Function $y(x)$} & \text{Derivative $y'(x)$} & \text{Value of $x$ for} \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{} & & & \text{which $y'=0$}\\
\midrule
\endhead

%% Footer information, all pages but final page
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\footnotesize\em(continued on following page)}\\
\endfoot

%% Footer information, final page
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% Body of longtable
& (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54} & \frac{5 (4 x^2-43 x+93)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} & 3 \\ 
\addlinespace
& (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54} & \frac{5 (4 x^2-43 x+93)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} & 3 \\ 
\addlinespace
& (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54} & \frac{5 (4 x^2-43 x+93)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} & 3 \\ 
\addlinespace
& (10 x+8) \sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}  & \frac{20 x^2-262 x+728}{\sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}}  & 4\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With this way, how can I number each row automatically? Because I have 174 rows.

Comment: @toandhsp - I've provided an addendum with a `longtable` that automatically inserts a row number.

Comment: If in my document have many longtable and number of columns of each  longtable are difference. Can you write a general code for every cases?

Comment: @toandhsp - I'm afraid I'm not sure what your new objective is. Please consider posting a *new query*, in which you state what it is you're trying to achieve. By posting a new query, it will be seen by many more people, raising the odds that somebody may be able to furnish a helpful answer.

Answer (score 5):

An variation of Mico answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,longtable}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{#1}}}
\newcounter{order}
\newcommand{\order}{\stepcounter{order}\theorder}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
{% <-- for limiting \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells to this table only   
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{longtable}{>{\order}c
                *{3}{>{$}l<{$}}
                  }
    \toprule
\mc{Oder}
    &    \mc{Function}    
            &   \mc{Derivative}    
                &   \mc{Solution}  \\

\midrule
   &   y = (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}
        &   y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} 
            &   x=3                             \\
   &   y = (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}
        &   y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} 
            &   x=3                             \\
   &   y = (10 x+10) \sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}
        &   y'=\dfrac{5 \left(4 x^2-43 x+93\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-15 x+54}} 
            &   x=3                             \\
   &   y = (10 x+8) \sqrt{x^2-18 x+80} 
        &   y'=\dfrac{20 x^2-262 x+728}{\sqrt{x^2-18 x+80}}
            &   x=4                             \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

For more space I used macros `\setcellgapes{3pt} \makegapedcells` from `\makecells` package, for numbering of equation serve macro `order`. 
Others is equal as at Mivo answer.

[image]